# Error 80010108 with autofill

Tags: excel, autofill

I´m writting a code but i´m getting an -2147417848 (80010108) error. I know that is caused everytime it "gets" a empty cell but i don´t know how to fix it, can someone help me please? Here´s the code

```
Dim i, g As Integer

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    g = 12

    For i = 3 To 5000

        If Worksheets("Registo_EPI´s").Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(4, 20).Value Then
            Cells(g, 21).Value = Worksheets("Registo_EPI´s").Cells(i, 5).Value
            g = g + 1
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Whenever a cell within the range Cells(i,5) is blank, the code crash. Por example if in cell(3,5) i have a number or date and if in cell(4,5) i don´t have anything, its crashes. Hope ou guys can help me. Thanks

Comment: Just to say i´ve managed to bypass the error with "On Error Resume Next" but i would like not to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's quite likely that your `Worksheet_Change` event handler is unintentionally calling itself and that this may be the source of your problem.

For example, if the `Worksheet_Change` event handler shown applies to `Sheet1` (and thus unqualified references like `Cells(4, 20).Value` also refer to `Sheet1`) then when you change the value of `Cells(g, 21)` the `Worksheet_Change` event handler for `Sheet1`is called again and so on.

You should use the `Target` parameter of the event handler to guard against this. If, for example, you were only interested in changes to `Cells(4, 20)` then you could have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If (Target.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) = "R4C20") Then
        g = 12

        For i = 3 To 5000

            If Worksheets("Registo_EPI´s").Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(4, 20).Value Then
                Cells(g, 21).Value = Worksheets("Registo_EPI´s").Cells(i, 5).Value
                g = g + 1
            End If

        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```